# Impact of Recycling Worker Process on WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, worker-process

i want to know what is the impact (in performance, availabillity, etc) that Recycling the Worker Process (IIS V 6.0) has over a WCF Service Hosted in IIS, i would also like to know if there's a best practice on how to configure the recycling time or # of requests.

I would also like to know if the Worker Process being recycled has something to do with an service that it's instantiation configuration is set to Single, does it has to instantiate it again after every worker process recycling?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525803(VS.90).aspx notes:

## Considerations When Recycling Applications

When applications are recycled, it is possible for session state to be lost. During an overlapped recycle, the occurrence of multi-instancing is also a possibility.

Loss of session state: Many IIS applications depend on the ability to store state. IIS 6.0 can cause state to be lost if it automatically shuts down a worker process that has timed out due to idle processing, or if it restarts a worker process during recycling.

Occurrence of multi-instancing: In multi-instancing, two or more instances of a process run simultaneously. Depending on how the application pool is configured, it is possible for multiple instances of a worker process to run, each possibly loading and running the same application code. The occurrence of an overlapped recycle is an example of multi-instancing, as is a Web garden in which two or more processes serve the application pool regardless of the recycling settings.

If your application cannot run in a multi-instance environment, you must configure only one worker process for an application pool (which is the default value), and disable the overlapped recycling feature if application pool recycling is being used.

---

I would encourage you to read through those articles on MSDN that pertain to your problem, and additionally, they should have a translation to Spanish to help with issues pertaining to difficulty to understand English with technical jargon.

Comment: Thanks, i really apreciate your time.